# Texture reflection on adjacent geometry surface

Tags: shader, webgl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, ogl

I am trying to replicate the reflection, of a video/image texture placed on the wall, on the floor below as seen in the attached image. As you can see, it's not merely mirroring the texture because there is a step on the floor, near the drums, and it is dark. Which means that the texture is 'emitting' a light.

For this project, I am using OGL, which is a low abstraction WebGl library. I can easily create the whole scene with the geometry, their placements, and the texture with no problems at all.

My only issue is how to make the texture act as a light source and form these reflections based on the texture's colors.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone gives me a direction about achieving it.

[image]

Comment: Which guideline did my question not meet, may I know?

Comment: I don't think it would be inconsistent with any guidelines... The colleague above, probably only edited the _aesthetics_. About question, maybe you will consider SSR https://discourse.threejs.org/t/need-help-understanding-an-issue-in-using-the-ssr-effect/53078

Comment: From the top of my head I'd say you have three options:
1. Implement area lights, basically you want to raytrace the plane of the textured wall, then sample from the texture using a mip level (as an approximation to properly calculated irradiance) based on the roughness of the surface.
2. Implement screenspace reflections, if your camera angle stays this low the results might be acceptable.
3. Put a few analytical lightsources (pointlights or spotlights) that roughly approximate the desired result

Comment: @LJᛃ thank you so much. But I am afraid it would be too technical for me. I wish stuff made in Blender could just be imported in Webgl with all this heavy lifting already done. The screenshot is actually from a Blender rendered video. Maybe WebGPU would make it possible, I donno. Thanks again